# Excel: Adding and Searching Replacing in Bulk from Many Sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, automation, spreadsheet

I've got a 650 sheet Excel document. I need to do some bulk additions to each of the sheets.

Are there ways to say add a bit of text to a specific row/column pair (A4), bulk search and replace, etc?

Comment: you can select all the sheets and then edit the cell in the active sheet and it will edit it on all sheets. Or are you wanting to do something else?

Comment: Yes, this seemed to work. I'm trying to normalize 650 sheets of data in preparation to create CSVs to in turn import into MYSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To edit the same cell on several sheets, you can select all applicable sheets and edit the cells on the active sheet, this will, in turn, edit that cell on all selected sheets.